# Highlight with color all words which starts with uppercase letter using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm newbie in Javascript and jQuery. I have a text inside a paragraph. I want to highlight with yellowgreen color all words which starts with uppercase letter.
Here is my source code. But it does not works properly.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
<style>
.mycls {background-color:yellowgreen}
</style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var str = $(p).text();

                words = str.split(' ');

                for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                    var w = words[i].split('');

                    if (w.charAt(0) === w.charAt(0).toUpperCase()) {
                        $(this).addClass("mycls");
                    }

                 //   words[i] = letters.join('');
                }
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>President of USA Barack Obama is ...</p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Thank you to all!

Comment: I'm still thinking of a simple solution but what is wrong with your code is that you have 1 <p> and you want to apply a css class to a part of a <P>. The only way I see it at the moment is : 1- You split your phrase in a word array 2- You remove from dom the <p> containing your sentence 3- You create a new <p> for every words with the class when needed and add it back to the dom. Will test if this works.

Comment: content inside paragraph tags is generated automatically. @Alexandre

Comment: Your code should work, but you'll need to wrap the matching word in a `<span>` then apply the class to that.

Comment: @mynhylisti yes, from your javascript you need to recompose the sentence so that each word has a <p> so that you can apply the p a class

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('p').each(function(){ // to each <p>
  r = /[A-Z]\w*/g; // big letter with word symbols, global search
  function f(x){
    return '<span class="y">'+x+'</span>' // rewrited
  }
  h = $(this).html(); //get
  h = h.replace(r,f); //replace
  $(this).html(h); //set
}) //done
```

```css
.y {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>President of USA Barack Obama is ...</p>
```

Comment: This code looks great but doesn't match OP requirements. He wants the word to be highlighted in yellow if it has a Capital letter first letter.

Comment: You may also use `color: yellowgreen;`

Comment: There you go, I didn't want to hijack your best answer (and complex looking at it, thanks for the comments) to modify it to fit OP's need. Great job ! EDIT : Just modified your code to change the background-color and not the text color to yellowgreen.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<p>President of USA Barack Obama is ...</p>
<style>
.highlighted
{
 background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
<script>
var split = $('p').text().split("");
var upperCase= new RegExp('[A-Z]');
$.each(split,function(i)
{
  if(split[i].match(upperCase))
  {
    $('p').html($('p').html().replace(split[i],'<span class=\"highlighted\">' + split[i] + '</span>')); 
  }
});
</script>
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/zhu7j8o6/5/